# Using linux shell command to insert CSV data into DB2

Tags: linux, csv, db2, db2-luw

I would require some help in inserting data from CSV file to CUSTOMER table using Shell script. Is it possible to retrieve the CSV data by comma instead of the fixed position of the data? For example, the data for my Remarks does not have a fixed position, i.e. it could contain 10 characters or 15 characters, hence the variable changes.

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSFILE=/credentials/systemcredential.properties
USERID=$(cat $PASSFILE | grep UserID | cut -f2 -d=)
PASSWORD=$(cat $PASSFILE | grep Pwd | cut -f2 -d=)

# connect to database
source /opt/db2home/db2profile
db2 connect to DBRPTGU user $USERID using $PASSWORD

#--------------------------------------------------#
# TABLE: CUSTOMER
#--------------------------------------------------#

#db2 "select count(*) from udbcuser.CUSTOMER"

db2 "load from /batchload/data/CUSTOMER.csv of asc
method L(1 7, 9 23, 25 39, 41 47, 49 68)
insert_update into udbcuser.CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,ITEM_PURCHASED,AMOUNT_PURCHASED,REMARKS)"
```

Sample data as requested:
9000001,Michael Tan,Wallet,$30,First time customer
9000002,Sally Gomez,Jacket,$90,
9000003,Cheng Ning,Boots,$80,Member
9000004,Richard Chin,Sunglasses,$30,Member

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using "of ASC" and not "of DEL" as file type?

Comment: You can use CSV files (`load from ... OF DEL modified by .... insert into...` ) but you have to be certain that the delimiter (for example a comma , by default) does not appear inside the data values. If the column delimiter can appear as data, either choose a different delimiter (`modified by coldel...` ) or continue to use fixed-width files if the data-files really do contain fixed-width column values.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script.

```
echo '9000001,Michael Tan,Wallet,$30,First time customer' > dat.csv
echo '9000002,Sally Gomez,Jacket,$90,' >> dat.csv
echo '9000003,Cheng Ning,Boots,$80,Member' >> dat.csv
echo '9000004,Richard Chin,Sunglasses,$30,Member' >> dat.csv

db2 -v drop db db1
db2 -v create db db1
db2 -v connect to db1
db2 -v "create table db2inst1.customer (num int, name char (30), item char (20), price char(10), remark char(20))"
db2 -v "load from dat.csv of del insert into db2inst1.customer"
db2 -v "select * from db2inst1.customer"
```

When you run, the last `select * from db2inst1.customer` returns as:

```
NUM         NAME                           ITEM                 PRICE      REMARK
----------- ------------------------------ -------------------- ---------- --------------------
    9000001 Michael Tan                    Wallet               $30        First time customer
    9000002 Sally Gomez                    Jacket               $90        -
    9000003 Cheng Ning                     Boots                $80        Member
    9000004 Richard Chin                   Sunglasses           $30        Member

  4 record(s) selected.
```

There is a lot of options for load command and here is V11.5 manual page for your reference:

**LOAD command**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html

Hope this helps.